# Shared Preferences with Option Menu

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I am assigned to use an implicit intent to open up a browser with a "Stock Ticker". The Stock ticker is just an extension to the url as seen in the code below. As I click a button to enter the url, the stock ticker is then stored as a shared preference and added to the option menu. I am able to access the option menu and open up a URL from the menu, the problem is if I constantly click the menu button it will add the menuItem even if it exists already. I tried using the contains method but it never came false so I must be storing the preferences incorrectly? Any help would be great!

```
package com.example.sharedpreferences;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText edit;
String StockTicker;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public static String MY_PREFS = "edu.college.ece3233.my_prefs";
SharedPreferences prefs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MyText);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menu.clear();
    return true;
}

public void SharedPreferenceClick(View view){
    StockTicker=edit.getText().toString();
    Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ StockTicker));
    startActivity(intent);
    editor.putString("StockTick", StockTicker);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    if(!prefs.contains(prefs.getString("StockTick", "")))
    menu.add(prefs.getString("StockTick", ""));
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent2 =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ item.toString()));
    startActivity(intent2);
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Shared Preferences, why not add the menu using the overloaded [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and provide a item id. You can use the method `findItem` to chck whether the menu is added or not. If the `MenuItem` is not found, this call would return `null`.

Comment: I would go that approach but it's a school assignment that focuses on Shared Preferences.